# When does the HST impact pre-purchased services in Ontario? [Canada]

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, sales-tax

Some services will be impacted earlier than July 1, 2010.  What services are impacted and what date does the full 13% get charged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Ontarians looking to beat the HST on pre-paid services that won’t be used until after July 1st have two days to make their purchase, as the **HST on pre-paid services goes into effect May 1st**, as per [this article](http://www.theprovince.com/news/Liberals+getting+debate/2955421/story.html) (among many I found online that say the same thing).